# Could not find method / java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

First of all I want to say that everything works great in Androids > 5.0 (API 21). This app was running nice and good until the last release, when hundreds of Kitkat users started complaining.

I am using proguard, the multidex feature, gradle is okay. Everything is good, compiling and working with no errors. The app is in production and things are great! Except that it is not working anymore for APIs 16, 17, 18 and 19.

Okay, I could change the minSdkVersion from 16 to 21 and that is it! But take a look at this installation stats:

```
. android 4.4 (api 19): 23.68%
. android 4.1 (api 16): 16.81%
. android 4.2 (api 17): 8.27%
. android 4.3 (api 18): 3.63%
```

So if I change the minSdkVersion from 16 to 21 I will exclude 52.39% of my users. This is not an option

The error I am getting:

```
Could not find method com.guilardi.questoeslibrary.db.MyDbHelper.getInstance, referenced from method com.guilardi.questoeslibrary.db.MyQuestion.sort
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 51463: Lcom/guilardi/questoeslibrary/db/MyDbHelper;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/guilardi/questoeslibrary/db/MyDbHelper;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

02-01 10:59:22.898 6677-6677/*** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.guilardi.questoeslibrary.db.MyDbHelper
                                                                               at com.guilardi.questoeslibrary.db.MyTest.setAsLast(Unknown Source)
```

But what is driving me nuts is that the unreachable method is in a Class that is in the very same package of the class that is calling it (com.guilardi.questoeslibrary.db). They are both being compiled together, the first one is reachable, the second one is not!

Anyone has any idea about this? Remember that it is only happening in APIs 16,17,18 and 19

Answer (score 0):

check your gradle file. There must be a variable minify = true. 
This was causing a trouble for me as well. So, check once by making it false.

Comment: I jus tried with minifyEnabled true or removing it and the error is still there